# lambda layer function definition without tf.keras.backend (Python Keras Package)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

[tf.keras.layers.Lambda](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) documentation explains how a function can be defined in a lambda layer. That document provides the following function as an example,

```
def antirectifier(x):

    x -= K.mean(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    x = K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)

    pos = K.relu(x)
    neg = K.relu(-x)

    return K.concatenate([pos, neg], axis=1)

model.add(Lambda(antirectifier))
```

But according to that, `tf.keras.backend` must be used to conduct operations on the input Tensor object.

Is there any way we can use default python packages and user-defined function to define the steps of a lambda function.

If it's possible, please be kind enough to provide some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using `import tensorflow` and its functions, there is absolutely no problem.

The code is perfect and that's it.

Just `import keras.backend as K`

Example `rounded = K.round(x)`

---

This is Keras independent documentation: https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda

Comment: But, for example, I simply tried to use round(x/3) in the body of the lamda function. Then I get "type Tensor doesn't define __round__ method".

Comment: Yes... you can't use "python" functions in tensors. You must use backend functions: https://keras.io/backend/ ---------- Keras does not exist without a backend, no matter which you choose, there is always one. (`K.round(x)`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *requirement* to use `tf.keras.backend` as such. The function that you give to keras.layers.Lambda() can do anything you want with the input tensor.

However, most 'default python packages' are simply not able to work with a Tensor object (e.g., as you noted in your comment, `round(x)` won't work on it).

You **can** use most of the Python language constructs on a tensor `x` (such as `x*2`, or `x+y`, etc) - the tensor objects implement those. Likewise, you can call some 'regular' python libraries, as long as they use only operations that are supported by tensors. For everything else, you will need to use either methods of the tensor object or appropriate Keras library functions - or write your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.